# Check and uncheck checkboxes after click one main checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

**This is not a duplicate of any question.I tried `Stackoverflow` answers but those are not helpful for me.**

I have one Select All Checkbox.If it  checked all other check boxes are checked, if I unchecked it all other check-boxes are unchecked.That's my task.

I tried it with these codes.But I failed.
Any help please.
Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<th width="10%" style="background-color: #cce5ff;"><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="checkbox select_all user_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" style="cursor: pointer;"></th>

<td width="10%">
    <input type="checkbox" id="view_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_v check_this_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="view" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if(!empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_view==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?>  name="per">     

    <input type="hidden" id="h_view_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="view_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_view;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
            <td width="10%">
                <input type="checkbox" id="edit_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_e check_this_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="edit" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if(!empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_edit==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?> name="per">
                <input type="hidden" id="h_edit_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="edit_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_edit;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
            <td width="7%">
                <input type="checkbox" id="delete_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" class="is_check_d check_this_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" value="delete" <?php if(isset($user['permission'])){if( !empty($user_permissions) && $user_permissions->can_delete==1){ echo 'checked';}else{echo '';}}?> name="per">
                <input type="hidden" id="h_delete_<?php echo $folder->id; ?>_<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>" name="delete_permission[][<?php echo $folder->id; ?>][<?php echo $user['user']->id; ?>]" value="<?php if(!empty($user_permissions)){ echo $user_permissions->can_delete;}else{ echo 0; } ?>">
            </td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".select_all").click(function () {

        user_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.each($('.check_this_'+user_id),function(){
            $(this).prop("checked", $('.user_'+user_id).prop("checked"));                

            $(this).click(function(){
                $('.user_'+user_id).prop("checked", false);           
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: "*...sometimes \[it's\] not working properly*" - and what does that mean, exactly? In what way is it "not working properly," what is it doing wrong? Or not doing at all? How often is "sometimes," does it always break in response to a certain event, or interaction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, in this case, as off-topic because there's no clear explanation as to what the problem is, how it manifests, what the code is doing wrong, or not doing at all. Please: take a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines, and clearly state what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: @David Thomas : Thank you very much to your advice and sorry for my mistakes.I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this trigger function is helpful for you.

```
$(".select_all").click(function() {

  user_id = $(this).attr('id');

  $.each($('.check_this_' + user_id), function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", $('.user_' + user_id).prop("checked"));
    $(this).trigger('change');
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.user_' + user_id).prop("checked", false);
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class name to your input fields.  then in your jquery function, add following code

```
if($(".select_all").checked == true){
    $$('input.class_name').each(function(checkbox) { checkbox.checked = true; });}
else{
    $$('input.class_name').each(function(checkbox) { checkbox.checked = false; });}
```